# How to adjust center of mass when going over obstacles?

Tags: ros, differential-drive, ros-kinetic, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi I have a robot currently setup using ROS-Kinetic and Gazebo. The machine has four wheels and a differential driving system. I am testing how the machine goes over street curbs and often times as the angle of the machine changes it falls backward. The real robot I am modeling adjusts its center of mass to go over obstacles such as curbs. Do you guys have any suggestions on how I should go about this feature?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19710/how-to-adjust-center-of-mass-when-going-over-obstacles?/) by [MRhinelander](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5614/mrhinelander/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How about adding a link which holds the amount of mass you want to move, and connecting that link to the rest of the robot by a prismatic joint you can control?

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MRhinelander](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5614/mrhinelander/) on 2018-06-15**:
I actually do have something like that. I have a wheel assembly on either side of the machine. Each with two wheels. I could hook this up to the main chassis with a prismatic joint. What is the best way to go about controlling this joint?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-15**:
I'd say similarly to how you're controlling the rest of the robot... Since you're using ROS you may want to use that here too